# Formatting the output of objdump -sj .text

Tags: linux, hexdump

I am hoping to get the contents of the .text section, of a Microsoft PE file using a linux command.  When I use

```
objdump -sj .text filename.exe
```

the output consists of the offset, in hexadecimal format, on the far left, followed by the content, in hexadecimal format, in the middle and a mixture of dots and ASCII characters on the right.  I don't know if the dots represent unprintable characters.  A screen shot follows. [image]

Is there a way to adjust the format of the output?  Ideally, I am hoping to get the printable strings without the hexadecimal numbers.  I have looked through the objdump man page but could not see a way to do this.

Comment: A screenshot or some sample output would help people understand your question...

Comment: I tried to add a screen shot but it's not filling the allotted space.  Thanks,

Comment: @OtagoHarbour did you find a solution to this? I am looking for an answer.